# Search value in multidimensional array and sum the value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to do a function that search a value inside a multidimensional array and adding up the value from the findings. The array is as below

```
    $arr = array (
        'MY106782'=> array ('code'=>"MY106782",'totalSales'=>"5625.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY246913"),
        'MY126192'=> array ('code'=>"MY126192",'totalSales'=>"5625.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY126637"),
        'MY128276'=> array ('code'=>"MY128276",'totalSales'=>"3180.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY106782"),
        'MY157278'=> array ('code'=>"MY157278",'totalSales'=>"5625.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY477500"),
        'MY167585'=> array ('code'=>"MY167585",'totalSales'=>"5625.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY106782")
    );
```

I'm trying to search all 'MY106782' inside the "SponsorID" array, get the 'totalSales' value when found and add the values if the is multiple records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your array is a key value pair arrays, you have to determine which key are you looking for. Check this:

```
$sponsor_id = "MY106782";
$total_sales = 0;
$arr = array (
    'MY106782'=> array ('code'=>"MY106782",'totalSales'=>"5625.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY246913"),
    'MY126192'=> array ('code'=>"MY126192",'totalSales'=>"5625.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY126637"),
    'MY128276'=> array ('code'=>"MY128276",'totalSales'=>"3180.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY106782"),
    'MY157278'=> array ('code'=>"MY157278",'totalSales'=>"5625.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY477500"),
    'MY167585'=> array ('code'=>"MY167585",'totalSales'=>"5625.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY106782")
);

foreach($arr as $values) {
    if($values["SponsorID"] == $sponsor_id) {
        $total_sales += (float)$values["totalSales"];
    }
}

echo $sponsor_id . " - " . $total_sales;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to something like this

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['SponsorID'] == 'MY106782') {
            $i++;
        }
 }
```

**Output:** 2

Comment: Hmm, $i = 1 inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script if key is exist only once time in a array.

```
 $arr = array (
    'MY106782'=> array ('code'=>"MY106782",'totalSales'=>"5625.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY246913"),
    'MY126192'=> array ('code'=>"MY126192",'totalSales'=>"5625.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY126637"),
    'MY128276'=> array ('code'=>"MY128276",'totalSales'=>"3180.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY106782"),
    'MY157278'=> array ('code'=>"MY157278",'totalSales'=>"5625.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY477500"),
    'MY167585'=> array ('code'=>"MY167585",'totalSales'=>"5625.00",'SponsorID'=>"MY106782")
    );
 $key_to_check = 'MY157278';
 if (array_key_exists($key_to_check, $arr)) {
    echo $arr[$key_to_check]['totalSales'];
 }else{
    echo "key not found."
 }
```